# Мультифон и Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

Здравствуйте!
Я пытаюсь создать транк Мультифон для Asterisk через FreePBX. Однако, какие бы настройки не применяла, в итоге все равно в отчете (sip show registry(в консоли) или Reports->Asterisk Info->Chan_SIP Info (в FreePBX)) выходит "state: Request Sent". Основные настройки были такими:

> **Peers Details**:
>   username=792<номер>
>   type=peer
>   secret=<пароль>
>   qualify=yes
>   notransfer=no
>   insecure=port,invite
>   host=193.201.229.35
>   fromuser=792<номер>
>   fromdomain=multifon.ru
>   disallow=all
>   allow=ulaw
>   dtmfmode=inband
>   **User Details**:
>   type=user
>   context=from-pstn
>   dtmfmode=inband
>   disallow=all
>   allow=ulaw
>   **Register String**:
>   792<номер>:<пароль>:792<номер>@193.201.229.35/792<номер>

Они были взяты с сайта http://trustore.ru/article/asterisk/213-multifon-in-freepbx
С софтфона звонки через Мультифон доступны, на сайте https://sm.megafon.ru/sm/client/routing установила статус 2 (для приема звонков через софтфон).
 Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, что не так?

Comment: Добрый день! В строке `Register String: 792<номер>:пароль>:792<пароль>@193.201.229.35/792<номер>` у вас наверно опечатка. Должно быть примерно так: `792<номер>:<пароль>:792<номер>@193.201.229.35/792<номер>` В остальном, проверять настройки NAT, `sip set debug on` в консоли астериска и смотреть что там происходит.

Comment: вы правы, ошиблась)

Comment: в консоли после sip _set debug_ on вывелось _Really destroing sip dialog  Method: OPTIONS_

Comment: state: Request Sent означает, что ваш сервер отправил запрос но ответа пока не получил. У вас сервер за NAT? Если да, то правильно ли выставлены параметры externip в sip.conf? Вообще в дебаге вам нужно поймать сообщение REGISTER от вашего сервера к серверу мультифона. Там сразу все станет видно.

Comment: вышло сообщение _Relly destruing SIP dialog '<идентификатор>@127.0.1.1' Method:Register_

Comment: не пойму почему он взял 127.0.1.1, если я везде указываю адрес компьютера в локальной сети?

Comment: asterisk настраивала на виртуальной машине Ubuntu 14, к настройкам nat при этом не прикасалась

Comment: Повторюсь, проблема скорее всего с настройкой NAT. Вам нужно для начала настроить параметры **externip**, **localnet** и **nat** в sip.conf. Ваш сервер скорее всего отправляет оператору в сообщении REGISTER локальный адрес (внутренний) а должен подставлять внешний. Поэтому оператор вам не может прислать ответный пакет. Полностью приведите сообщение REGISTER, там есть строки To: From: Contact:, что в них?

Comment: Retransmitting  #1 (NAT) to 193.201.229.35:5060
REGISTER sip:193.201.229.35 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 192.168.0.105:5061; branch=zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz; rport 
Max-Forwards: 70
From: <sip:792<номер>@193.201.229.35>;tag=as64aee47b
To: <sip:792<номер>@193.201.229.35>
Call-ID: <набор чисел>@127.0.1.1
CSeq: 146 REGISTER
Contact: <sip:792<номер>@192.168.0.105:5061>

Comment: вижу: в заголовке идет обращение к 127.0.1.1, а дальше везде указан локальный адрес.

Comment: Разрешите еще такой вопрос, какой файл нужно будет редактировать? тот, что находится в /etc/asterisk или тот, что находится в каталоге откуда я устанавливала Astrerisk?

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо правильно настроить asterisk на работу с NAT. Прочитать немного про это можно, например, тут: https://voipnotes.ru/nastroika-asterisk-i-nat/

> какой файл нужно будет редактировать? тот, что находится в
>   /etc/asterisk

Основной конфиг. файл чистого asterisk находится в /etc/asterisk/sip.conf В FreePBX, к сожалению, я не подскажу. Возможно есть настройка в графическом режиме. http://wiki.freepbx.org/display/FPG/Asterisk+SIP+Settings+User+Guide Также потребуется на роутере настроить проброс портов для RTP на ваш сервер asterisk

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

register => 792xxxxxxxx@multifon.ru: pasSWORD123:792xxxxxxxx@sbc.megafon.ru:5060/792xxxxxxx

взято с мануала мегафона